# How to microbenchmark an algorithm on an ARM laptop?

Tags: arm, benchmarking, apple-m1, microbenchmark

On a servers or a desktops it's reasonable to just disable frequency scaling and then one can run microbenchmarks.

But how do you meaningfully run microbenchmarks on a arm? (Given different cores and energy efficiency)

Specific context:
Processor: M2
Microbenchmakrs for basic algorithms (think sort, strlen - a long those lines).
I am interested in measuring both energy efficient and high-performance cores.

*UPD: to avoid confusion: I'm pretty sure the library (GoogleBenchmark) can measure the time correctly. I just want to run the binary correctly*

Comment: *disable frequency scaling* - Even that's not always realistic for some benchmarks.  At lower frequency, DRAM latency is fewer core clock cycles, since the DRAM controller usually stays at the same frequency, even when individual cores and/or the shared L3 and interconnects between cores clock themselves down.

Comment: But for workloads not super sensitive to off-core memory latency, like strlen over buffers hot in L2 cache, you can get consistent results from timing in core clock cycles instead of nanoseconds.  On x86, that means using HW performance counters; `rdtsc` runs at a fixed frequency, unrelated to the core clock.  Presumably M1/M2 have performance counters, too.  If you can at least record the average clock over the benchmark interval, with thread affinity set to a specific core, that's a lot better than nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I would really hope that the benchmarking library would do that for me though, they support arm. My questions is purely about how to run the binary. Let me update that.

Comment: My point was that you *don't* want to measure time.  Instead, measure core clock cycles, since performance in cycles is often invariant with CPU frequency.  (Except when off-core traffic like cache misses are involved.)  If the CPU has to pause to change frequency in the middle of a benchmark, that adds a lot of overhead, which is why you normally want to discard outliers and take the median or best.